# Fast switching wmii and unity

Tags: unity

I'm developing user interfaces, and while developing in wmii it's critical that I get the same user experience that users for unity would get. So does anyone know how to make fast switching between wmii and unity, or better to run wmii in unity or vice versa?

I'm thinking about Virtualbox if everything fails.

Is it possible to have on Ctrl-Alt-F1 unity and Ctrl-Alt-F7 wmii for example?